# List of orders to be captured using PayPal api

Tags: api, paypal, capture

We are finding that a number of orders - for some as yet unknown reason - are not automatically captured. Is there a way with the API to get a list of un-captured orders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TransactionSearch API. TransactionSearch API can help you to list down all the transaction together with the status of the transaction itself. You can specified a date range and also the status of the transaction. Read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) for the API details.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I do get all the transactions, but I get no indicator of a payment needing to be "captured". I get pending payment and pending debits. Captured payments are not received funds, so I can't filter results as far as I can tell.